# Is there a cleaner way to write this code? D&D dice roller

Tags: python, python-3.x

I feel it is very straight forward and easy to read code but I was wondering if there is a simple or more efficient way to write this.
This is the beginning of my first project.

```
import random

command = "".lower()

def dice():
    while True:
        dice_entry = input(":> ").lower().strip()
        if dice_entry == "help":
            print("""
Valid commands include:
Coin, d4, d6, d8, d10, d12 or d20
in order to roll the corresponding dice
or flip a coin.

Type Quit to close program.""")

        elif dice_entry == "coin":
            print("".join(random.choices(['Heads', 'Tails'])))

        elif dice_entry == "d4":
            print(random.randint(1, 4))

        elif dice_entry == "d6":
            print(random.randint(1, 6))

        elif dice_entry == "d8":
            print(random.randint(1, 8))

        elif dice_entry == "d10":
            print(random.randint(1, 10))

        elif dice_entry == "d12":
            print(random.randint(1, 12))

        elif dice_entry == "d20":
            print(random.randint(1, 20))

        elif dice_entry == "quit":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid command. Type \"Help\" for list of valid commands.")
```

Comment: You could read the message, check that complies with your format "dXX". If yes, remove the 'd' and transform the remining text to int and then call the 'random.randint(1,xx)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is :

Naming of variables : your variable dice_entry has a bad name. You can also throw a coin, or quit, or type help which has nothing to do with dice.

Use of `random.choices` : you could use `random.choice` instead and avoid using `"".join`

[WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) : some code is duplicated multiple times and you could use a function for it.

Useless code : what is the point of command variable ? Especially what is the point of `"".lower()` ? Why not just `""`

```
import random

def throw_dice(nb_faces):
    return random.randint(1, nb_faces)

def throw_coin():
    return random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])

def main():
    while True:
        entry = input(":> ").lower().strip()

        if entry == "help":
            print("""
Valid commands include:
Coin, d4, d6, d8, d10, d12 or d20
in order to roll the corresponding dice
or flip a coin.

Type Quit to close program.""")

        elif entry == "coin":
            print(throw_coin())

        elif entry in ["d4", "d6", "d8", "d10", "d12", "d20"]:
            nb_faces = int(entry[1:])
            print(throw_dice(nb_faces))

        elif entry == "quit":
            break

        else:
            print('Invalid command. Type "Help" for list of valid commands.')
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to use an addressing dictionary:

```
import random

def dice():
    help_message = (
        "Valid commands include:\n"
        "Coin, d4, d6, d8, d10, d12 or d20 in order to roll the corresponding dice or flip a coin.\n"
        "Type Quit to close program.\n"
    )
    commands_dict = {
        "help": lambda: help_message,
        "coin": lambda: random.choice(("Heads", "Tails")),
        "d4"  : lambda: random.randint(1,  4),
        "d8"  : lambda: random.randint(1,  8),
        "d10" : lambda: random.randint(1, 10),
        "d12" : lambda: random.randint(1, 12),
        "d20" : lambda: random.randint(1, 20)
    }
    default = lambda: "Invalid command. Type \"Help\" for list of valid commands."
    while True:
        dice_entry = input(":> ").lower().strip()
        if dice_entry == "quit":
            break
        print(commands_dict.get(dice_entry, default)())
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/IllLavishBruteforceprogramming)